# Why the chaincode in my hyperledger fabric network taking 1.45gb space?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[image: I'm uploading the image of my docker containers with their respective sizes.]

I'm uploading the image of my docker containers with their respective sizes.

Comment: What type of chaincode are you using ? node, Go, Java ?

Comment: @david_k I'm using node right now.

Comment: The actual text of your Dockerfile would be essential to diagnose this (please don't paste screenshots of terminal windows into SO questions!).  But from what you've shown it looks like you're just starting from very large Docker Hub base images.

Comment: The current runtime container used for NodeJS is massive.  We have greatly reduced the size in the 2.0 release

Comment: It uses fabric-baseimage

Comment: @GariSingh if i write my chaincode in go, will it help ? and currently I'm using hyperledger fabric 1.4.1, if i change to 1.4..2 are there massive changes ? what would you suggest me for production environment whether i should stick to 1.4.1 or 2.0 ?

Comment: The runtime container for Go is much smaller for sure.
1.4.2 will use the same basic containers as of right now.
But it's fine to use either 1.4.1 or 1.4.2 ... I would not wait for 2.0 just based on container sizes.   FWIW ... in 2.0 we moved to Alpine which gives us much smaller images and we also built a dedicated Node CC image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Fabric 1.4.x, the default runtime container for NodeJS chaincode is based on fabric-baseimage which is around 1.4GB.  Fabric 2.0 and later leverage a dedicated, Alpine-based container for Node CC with a much smaller overall footprint.